# When I set the thermostat to X degrees, is that the temperature at which air is pushed out through the vents?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, thermostat

My hunch is that most ac units aren't that sophisticated, and they just pump air that is "cold enough" or "hot enough" and pump it until temperature rises to the specified value. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thermostat temperature is of the room, at the thermostat. The thermostat has a differential of about 1 or so degrees. Meaning if it is set for 70 deg, it will kick on @ 69 degs., then off @ 70 deg. The actual temperature of the ducts will be something different.

EDIT:
The question is about AC so it is ductwork. Each register is likely to be at a somewhat different temperature & CFM due to duct length, size, how many turns, etc. This is often measured with an anemometer.

Comment: There's a double negative here.  The question title asks if the temp pushed out is a specific temp, but the question assumes otherwise and asks if this is incorrect...  Your answer is right but when I first read it I was confused..

Comment: Also, this only really holds true for forced air systems.  Electric heaters are one type of heating can vary the temperature

Comment: It is also worth noting that you can have varied fan speed. Not exactly what he is asking about, but worth knowing about.

Comment: Air temp & CFM will vary from each register (see my edit).